# How to get the onclick button to replace the function values instead of adding them

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a simple adding calculator within an HTML form to get to know javascript a bit better. The javascript looks like this -

```
function add() {
var x = document.getElementById("numberOne").value;
var y = document.getElementById("numberTwo").value; 
return parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
}
```

The HTML -

```
<form>
<input id="numberOne" type="number"/></br>
<input id="numberTwo" type="number"/></br>
<input type="button" value="Calculate"
onclick="document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(add()));"/>
</form>
```

Now, upon clicking the button, what happens is it just adds the values as a straight line. For instance, if I enter 5 and 5 and click Calculate 3 times I get 101010 instead of 10 three separate times.

I'd like for it to either replace the output or alternatively display it on a separate line and not as a straight line.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate result div and then overwrite it each time:

```
<form>
<input id="numberOne" type="number"><br>
<input id="numberTwo" type="number"><br>
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="button" value="Calculate"
onclick="document.getElementById('result').innerText = add();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mehuls answer is correct, but...

- Don't apply action inside onclick attribute, You should handle it with event listener
- Assign **result** element to variable, so Your script will not search
  for this element in whole DOM tree every time You click the button
- Use **textContent** instead of **innerText** because innerText will cause browser reflows